# How To Create a User in MonogoDB Database using loopback4

Tags: mongodb, loopback, loopback4

I would like to know, How to create a user inside a MongoDB database (which was dynamically created) and assign a role (eg: userAdmin) to it, using loopback4

Comment: please let us know what you have done so far?

Comment: Used Loopback Execute Command to create user. but it failed. now using mongo client package to do so